# Run java class from specific jar using cron job

Tags: java, jar, cron

I need to run a java class from a specific jar file using cron job in linux. I have tried absolute paths for both java and the folder which contains all the jar files in a shell file and it runs manually just fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
/absolute/path/to/java -cp "absolute/path/to/libs/*" com.xxx.MyClass
```

when I try to run this shell file from a cron job it fails

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/script.sh
```

The folder libs contains multiple jar dependencies.
I doubt that MyClass should be an absolute path also.

Answer (score 0):

That's **NOT** an 'absolute/path/to/libs'... that's a relative path.

Additionally, you need to specify the jar file that contains your class

```
java -jar /absolute/path/to/jarfile.jar -cp /absolute/plath/to/libs com.xxx.MyClass
```

Get yourself a decent tutorial on executing JAR files...

https://www.baeldung.com/java-run-jar-with-arguments

Comment: the jarfile is not executable in this case.